# SpringBoot, how to access a map from another class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have this class that allows me to register data repositories to access in another component.

Overall idea is that I have a map and I can reference each individual repository by an associated key (which is just a string).

## What I found debugging:

From my debugging, it looks like the value in the map is null when I want it to be a reference to each JpaRepository, which makes me believe the wiring for that isn't working correctly.

## My Two Questions:

1) I would like to make the map static, but still be able to access the repositories with no issues

2) This actually isn't working in an associated consumer class, my spring-boot server fails to start with a NPE.

## Example Usage In Associated Consumer Class:

```
@Autowired private DataLoaderRegistrar loaderConstants;
```

Above is how I *think* this should be declared? Hopefully this can change if it becomes static.

I am looping through objects in my class and calling this `DataLoaderRegistrar` class using this:

> #### Brief Explanation of forEach Below:
>
> I have several types I am iterating over, this grabs the class name of each associated datatype (which is the key in the map) then calls the save method on the associated JPA repository.

```
.forEach(
    dataType -> {
      loaderConstants.getRepo(dataType.toString()).save(dataType);
    });
```

## DataLoaderRegistrar Class

```
@Component
public class DataLoaderRegistrar {

  /** Auto wired all {@link JpaRepository} references here to support storing test data in DB */
  @Autowired public UserRepository userRepo;

  @Autowired public GoalRepository goalRepo;

  /**
   * All registered entities can go here with an association to their repository as the value
   * Examples can be seen in {@link com.habicus.core.data GoalRepository} as well as {@link
   * com.habicus.core.entities.Goal}
   */
  private Map<String, JpaRepository> reposByName =
      new HashMap<String, JpaRepository>() {
        {
          put(User.class.getSimpleName(), userRepo);
          put(Goal.class.getSimpleName(), userRepo);
        }
      };

  public DataLoaderRegistrar() {}

  /**
   * Returns the requested repository that is stored in the
   *
   * @param className
   * @return {@link JpaRepository} that is associated with a particular class name
   */
  public JpaRepository getRepo(String className) {
    return reposByName.get(className);
  }

  /**
   * Method returns a {@link Map} which has a {@link String} as the key and an associated {@link
   * JpaRepository} as the value, which represents a CRUD repository for all supported data types in
   * our system
   */
  public Map<String, JpaRepository> retrieveAllDataRepositories() {
    return reposByName;
  }
}
```

## Stack Trace

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:389)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun.exec(BootRun.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        ... 30 more
```

## Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.habicus.repository.Loader.lambda$loadTestContainers$0(Loader.java:155) ~[main/:na]
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1255) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at com.habicus.repository.Loader.loadTestContainers(Loader.java:153) ~[main/:na]
        at com.habicus.repository.Loader.onApplicationEvent(Loader.java:120) ~[main/:na]
        at com.habicus.repository.Loader.onApplicationEvent(Loader.java:49) ~[main/:na]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at com.habicus.CoreApplication.main(CoreApplication.java:29) [main/:na]
```

## Code Near Failure (L155):

```
    Arrays.stream(resources)
        .map(this::ingestFromFile)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .map(Container.class::cast)
        .map(Container::getAll)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(
            dataType -> {
              loaderConstants.getRepo(dataType.toString()).save(dataType);
              LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Saved: " + dataType);
            });
  }
```

Comment: Where do you register your `@Bean`?

Comment: I guess I didn't do that at all.. Never used SpringBoot, how should I go about that?

Comment: Show us the stacktrace

Comment: U can only use autowired inside components..

Comment: @Glim added stack trace

Comment: @RyanS did you check to see that each part of ```.forEach(
    dataType -> {
      loaderConstants.getRepo(dataType.toString()).save(dataType);
    });``` is not null?

Comment: @mhradek added the code. Just a really big stream. I think I can see that the values in the map are null because the jpa repositories aren't being injected into it properly during the instantiation phase and I don't know why.

Comment: this `Loader` class is a Component?

Comment: I threw a component annotation on there, but it doesn't need to be there, I wasn't totally sure what I was doing. It runs during bootup time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reposByName` is initialized when Spring instantiates `DataLoaderRegistrar` but at this moment repos are mot injected yet. To resolve it you can annotate some method with `@PostConstruct` annotation. Spring will invoke this method after all dependencies are injected.

```
Component
public class DataLoaderRegistrar {

  @Autowired public UserRepository userRepo;

  @Autowired public GoalRepository goalRepo;

  @PostConstruct  
  public void registerRepos() {
    reposByName = new HashMap<String, JpaRepository>();
    reposByName.put(User.class.getSimpleName(), userRepo);
    reposByName.put(Goal.class.getSimpleName(), userRepo);
  }

  ...
}
```

More info https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle

Comment: Bingo! Thank you !